# Angular Drag and Drop Lists - Access nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using [Angular Drag and Drop Lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) in my project to great success, however I have a more complex use case, essentially being able to access a nested `ng-repeat` array. While [this nested demo](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested) exists, it handles a different use case.

Basically I have the following structure summarized for readability:

```
<div ng-repeat="imgArray in document.images">
    <div ng-if="doc._id === imgArray.document_template_id">
        <ul dnd-list="placedList">
            <li ng-repeat="img in imgArray.files" dnd-draggable="img" dnd-moved="img.splice($index, 1)">
                <!-- Display -->
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

However when the drag is finished and `dnd-moved="img.splice($index, 1)"` is called an error is thrown: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined`

I also tried to use `dnd-moved="imgArray.files.splice($index, 1)"`, and it throws the same error. The difference is that if I drag an existing element within the list using `img.splice` the element will 'disappear' without getting moved, just deleted and throwing the TypeError, when I use `imgArray.files` the element will not disappear or get reordered, only the TypeError is thrown.

I do need to create the nested `ng-repeat`, because the `ng-if` is an absolutely vital part of the process.

Any advice on how to make the `.splice()` work as intended would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dnd-moved="imgArray.files.splice($index, 1)"` should be working for you.  Can you reproduce in a Plunkr?  Also, are you sure that `imgArray.files` is something and not undefined?

Comment: I'm sure it's defined, since the `<!-- Display -->` part of the code above uses the `img` part successfully. As far as replicating goes, I'll try, maybe tomorrow, new years celebrations and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will actually work straight up, the problem with what the above was created due to copy-paste carelessness.

The line:

```
<ul dnd-list="placedList">
```

Needed to be:

```
<ul dnd-list="imgArray.files">
```

Just that change will make the nested ng-repeats work.